# why cannot pass an array created inside a function to a pointer?

Tags: c, arrays

`getLine` returns the array which store char of standard input. I try to print out the string in the array only get some other character, not the input. What is wrong with the function?

```
char *file_name;

file_name = getLine("enter the file name");
printf("%s\n", file_name);

char *getLine(char *question){
    printf("%s\n", question);
    char c, answer[100];
    int i = 0;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n'){
        answer[i++] = c;
        c = getchar();

    }
    answer[i] = '\0';
    return answer;

}
```

Comment: You are returning to a pointer to summat on the stack. This is destroyed at the end of the function

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`answer` is an automatic local variable which does not exist once the function return and therefore a pointer to it will become invalid. Never return a pointer to an automatic local variable.

Pointer to `static` local variable can be returned

```
static char answer[100];
```

or you can use dynamic allocation

```
char *answer = malloc(100);
```

Comment: is there any other way to obtains value of the array answer other than passing an external array?

Answer (score 2):

**Issue:**

```
{
   char c, answer[100];
   //code
   return answer;       <--- Here
}
```

`answer` is local to `getLine()` with automatic storage. Once the `getLine()` function finishes execution, there is no existance of `answer`. Therefore, you may not return the address of the local variable.

*Moral of the Story: enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them.*

**Workaround:**

To achieve what you want you have to either

- define `answer` as a pointer and allocate memory dynamically using `malloc()`/`calloc()`. Dynamically allocated memory has a global scope.

or

- define the `answer` array as `static`.

The first approach is recommended (and my personal fav, too). Make a note to `free()` the allocated memory once you're done using that to avoid memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

Functions can return `char *` but not array in C.

`answer` is a local variable to function `getLine()` and returning local variable address leads to undefined behavior

```
char *getLine(char *question)
{
   char *answer = malloc(100);
   //Perform your stuff here
   return answer;//This is valid because the memory is on heap
}
```